# Laravel Migrations with Artisan - 'SQL table does not exists' error

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, database-migration

While creating and testing migrations files for a MySQL database I receive the following error -

```
{"error":{"type":"Illuminate\\Database\\QueryException","message":"SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'laravel.entities' doesn't exist (SQL: select * from `entities`)","file":"\/Applications\/MAMP\/htdocs\/laravel\/vendor\/laravel\/framework\/src\/Illuminate\/Database\/Connection.php","line":555}}
```

What does not make sense is that I am using artisan to run the migrations and nothing in my migrations files is trying to run a `SELECT` query.

The artisan command I am using is `php artisan migrate` (also tried resetting with `php artisan:reset` and `php artisan:refresh`).

The relevant migration file content is:

```
public function up()
    {
            Schema::create('entities', function(Blueprint $table)
            {
                $table->increments('id')->unsigned();
                //..some more columns..
                $table->timestamps();
            }); 
    }
```

There are other migration files (total 10 files) but non of them has any dependency on the 'entities' table.

Trying to wrap my head around why artisan is running a SELECT query on the entities table instead of creating the table?

When I manually create the `entities` table (and add `if (!Schema:hasTable('entities') to bypass the creation of the new table)`, everything works fine so I'm positive that the other migration files are not causing the problem.

Config files and the database connection are all good.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Sidenote : the `increments()` function already uses unsigned integers by default.

Comment: @André thanks, good to know..still banging my head over this problem though...any idea what's going on?

Comment: @André tried, same problem.

Comment: still same problem. I even deleted the database and created a new one. does artisan try to run any of the models/controllers/views in the app folder? cause that's the only reason it I can think of for the SELECT query..

Comment: What does 'php artisan migrate' return when you run it without manually creating the table?

Comment: @Kisuka it returns the error I posted at the question - `1146 Table 'laravel.entities' doesn't exist (SQL: select * from `entities`)`

Comment: @André tested the migration files on a new installation, and it works(!). did not solve the problem but at least it's a clue...

Comment: @Yani so the migration itself isn't an issue. Do you have code that can interfere with the DB (for example listening to DB events using `DB::listen()`) ?

Comment: @André nothing that I know of, I checked for DB::listen...will look further

Comment: @André I was able to find the problem using your pointer and some more testing. Posted a new answer but unfortuntaly I was not able to accept your answer so I +1 you. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @Yani you can only accept an answer after some amount of time to give the community a chance to post other answers. Tomorrow you'll be able to accept it. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution, with the help and pointers by @Andre:

Turns out that Laravel's artisan has dependency on the `routes.php` file, which was making a call to the database. While some would say it's not best practice to make calls to the database from `routes.php`, this project requires it (I'm using caching to reduce preformance loss)
.
The following was causing artisan to crash while doing the migration (inside routes.php):

```
foreach (Entities::all() as $entity)
{
}
```

I was able to bypass it by adding the following to the routes.php file:

```
if (Schema::hasTable('entities'))
{
    foreach (Entities::all() as $entity)
     {
     }
}
```

Thanks @Andre for the pointers!

Comment: Thanks! I was calling the database from a provider, which artisan also depends on.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have added any code in Kernel.php or any other laravel infra files. artisan migrate invokes routes and kernel PHP files.

Comment the methods which might be querying these tables.

Comment: This should have been a comment instead of a solution. Unless you're specifically telling the user how to solve his problem, you should post as a comment on his question.

Answer (score -1):

Had the same problem.

If you are working with ACL (Access control list) check the authServiceProvider for you definition of gates an then put the if statement arround it, worked for me.